# LWC Jest test fails when testing data returned after apex imperative call

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest, imperativeapex

I believe it is a simple fix, but I am new to everything and Jest being the latest one I am exposed to.

I am trying to test if the lightning-combobox received the data to fill its options after the apex imperative call.

I still have no clue what I am doing, I have been copying code from orgs other components
The error I receive is on the data being returned, I expect two records to be returned from the mock data, but it received undefined.

Here is the mock data -

```
[
    {
        "value": "00T2h00000BC9naEAD",
        "label": "Test Task 2 | 2021-08-06 10:00 AM | owner name"
    },
    {
        "value": "00T2h00000BC9naTAS",
        "label": "Test Task 2 | 2021-08-06 10:05 AM | owner name"
    }
]
```

Here is component HTML

```
<lightning-combobox class="tasksList" label="Select Task"             
   options={tasks}
   value={defaultTask}
   onchange={handleTaskSelection} required>
</lightning-combobox>
```

Here is the JS -

```
connectedCallback() {
    getTasksAssociatedToContact({
        contactRecordId: this.contactRecordId
    }).then(data => {
        if (data) {               
            this.tasks = data.map(item => {
                return {
                    value: item.Id,
                    label: item.Subject + ' | ' + item.CreatedDate + ' | ' + item.Owner.Name,
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the LWC Jest Test, I am attaching the whole Jest code as I dont know what helps you all to help me -

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import { registerApexTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest';
import getTasksAssociatedToContact from "@salesforce/apex/PopulateTasksForContactController.getTasksAssociatedToContact";
import PopulateTasksForContact from 'c/populateTasksForContact';

jest.mock('lightning/flowSupport', () => {
    return 'FlowNavigation';
},
    { virtual: true }
);

const mockData = require('./data/tasksData.json');
const noMockData = require('./data/notasksData.json');
const getTasksAssociatedToContactAdapter = registerApexTestWireAdapter(getTasksAssociatedToContact);

describe('c-populate-tasks-for-contact', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
        // Prevent data saved on mocks from leaking between tests
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });
    describe('getTasksForContact Apex @imperative call', () => {
        it('renders tasks to combobox if data returned from imperative apex call', () => {
            const element = createElement('c-populate-tasks-for-combobox', {
                is: PopulateTasksForContact
            });
            element.contactRecordId = '0032h00000YxNzIAAV';
            document.body.appendChild(element);

            getTasksAssociatedToContactAdapter.emit(mockData);

            return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                let combobox = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.tasksList');
                expect(combobox.length).toBe(2);
            })
        })
    })
});
```

Please advise.

Comment: Does it verify that it did grab something when getting the component's shadowroot? Also JEST testing is very different. I just spent the last 2 weeks doing these so I feel your pain. [youtube vids that helped me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gF89vETTTBY&list=PLSWzWO4OqYArc_IIVbY14wWxPWDmV4SQr)

Comment: Yes it does, but I was able to make something work for now. But I still don't understand how it worked. Have to work on it more.

Comment: Could you go ahead and add your solution to your question, that way others can see it. JEST on LWCs don't have that many solutions/examples people could reference.

Comment: Sure will do once I am back to my desk.

Answer (score 3):

[lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) is a good resource for examples of how to mock different LWC scenarios. For your situation, there's an example of [apexImperativeMethodWithParams](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithParams).

In this scenario, you have to do two things:

1. Mock the imported module (the import statement for your apex method).
2. Provide data to return for the mocked imperative apex call

Based on what you provided, it seems you have some confusion or have copied from code that is **testing wire adapters**. You're using `emit()` which is an API to provide mocked data related to wire services in tests. [Write Jest Tests for Lightning Web Components That Use the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_wire_utility) and the trailhead for [Write a Jest Test for Wire Service](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/write-a-jest-test-for-wire-service) go over this.

> The generic adapter emits data on demand when you call the emit() API.

Going back to our #1 and #2 above, it's important to understand some things if you've gotten used to copying and pasting.

1. [jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) allows us to mock a whole module
2. [jest.fn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992628/how-does-jest-fn-work) creates a mock function

To do #1, you mock the imported module related to your apex method used in the call. In this, you'll see we return `jest.fn()` which is a new, unused mock function. The `virtual: true` part is because this mock is for a module that doesn't exist anywhere in the system.

```javascript
// Mocking imperative Apex method call
jest.mock(
    '@salesforce/apex/PopulateTasksForContactController.getTasksAssociatedToContact',
    () => {
        return {
            default: jest.fn()
        };
    },
    { virtual: true }
);
```

Now, we need to provide the value to control what is returned in this mocked imperative call for a success. We can do this with [mockResolvedValue()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue). That is syntactic sugar function for:

`jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(value));`

You'll see that this is returning a resolved promise (with the value you provide). You can correlate this within your code as the path that occurs within your `.then()` branch of your imperative apex call.

```javascript
connectedCallback() {
    getTasksAssociatedToContact({
        contactRecordId: this.contactRecordId
    }).then(data => {
        //resolved promise - pass mocked data or empty to test different scenarios
        }
    })
}
```

There is also [mockRejectedValue()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvaluevalue) which is useful for testing the non-happy path if you implemented error handling through `.catch()`

```javascript
    getTasksAssociatedToContact({
        contactRecordId: this.contactRecordId
    }).then(data => {

        }
    }). catch((error) => {
        //the rejected promise path
    }).
```

Knowing all that above, you provide the value like so

`getTasksAssociatedToContactAdapter.mockResolvedData(mockData);`

One last thing, you seem to have nested `describe` calls, but the following explains the [difference between describe and it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055287/what-is-the-difference-between-describe-and-it-in-jest). `describe` breaks your test suite into components and `it` is where you perform individual tests whose expectation can be expressed in a sentence `it lists returned tasks from imperative apex`. With that and the above, you get something looking like this:

```javascript
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import getTasksAssociatedToContact from "@salesforce/apex/PopulateTasksForContactController.getTasksAssociatedToContact";
import PopulateTasksForContact from 'c/populateTasksForContact';


jest.mock(
'@salesforce/apex/PopulateTasksForContactController.getTasksAssociatedToContact',
    () => {
        return {
            default: jest.fn()
        };
    },
    { virtual: true }
);

describe('c-populate-tasks-for-contact', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
        // Prevent data saved on mocks from leaking between tests
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });


    it('renders tasks to combobox if data returned from imperative apex call', async () => {

        //assign mock value for resolved apex promise
        getTasksAssociatedToContactAdapter.mockResolvedData(mockData);

        const element = createElement('c-populate-tasks-for-combobox', {
            is: PopulateTasksForContact
        });
        element.contactRecordId = '0032h00000YxNzIAAV';
        document.body.appendChild(element);

            
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            let combobox = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.tasksList');
                expect(combobox.length).toBe(2);
        });
    });
});
```